# How to call function at parent of returned class?

Tags: php

I have this simple code:

```
class Main {

    protected $setting;

    public function __construct($setting = false)
    {
        $this->setting;
    }

    public function call($param)
    {
        //do some stuff
        //$this->setting
    }

    public function groupA()
    {
        return new GroupA();
    }
}

class GroupA {

    public function methodA()
    {
        //how to call call('method') at Main function
    }
}

$obj = new Main();
$obj->groupA()->methodA();
```

How can I run function call() at Main class at method MethodA at GroupA class?
How to access to this function?

Comment: Return `Main` class object in `methodA()`.

Comment: This looks more like a design problem, you have a class returning a new object which needs to refer to the original class - it's going round in circles.  Difficult to tell with the class names if there is a better alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by "Main function" ? Shouldn't be a "Main class" ?
You can try to do this:
 public function groupA() { return new GroupA($this); } and set the valid constructor in the GroupA() class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the Main class via the constructor to the GroupA class. Don't forget that you can use only public methods there.

You may also be interested in [composition design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

```
class Main
{
    ...

    public function groupA() : GroupA
    {
        return new GroupA($this);
    }
}

class GroupA
{
    /** @var Main */
    private $main;

    ...

    public function __construct(Main $main) {
        $this->main = $main;
    }

    ...

    public function methodA($params) : void
    {
        return $this->main->call($param) ;
    }
}

// usage
$obj = new Main();
$obj->groupA()->methodA($params);
```

Comment: This solution looks god axcept when I want call function as private or protected.

Comment: Ohh changing: public function __construct(Main $main) -> public function __construct($main) , it worx as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main
{
    protected $setting;

    public function __construct($setting = false)
    {
        $this->setting;
    }

    public function call($param)
    {
        //do some stuff
        //$this->setting
    }

    public function groupA()
    {
        //Intantiating And passing intance on main using setter in GroupA
        return (new GroupA())->setMain($this);
    }
}

class GroupA
{

    private $_main;

    public function setMain( $main )
    {
        $this->_main = $main;
        return $this ;
    }

    public function methodA( $params = [] )
    {
        return $this->_main->call($params) ;
    }
}

$obj = new Main();
$obj->groupA()->methodA($params);
```

I used setter here , you can also use __constructor($main) in GroupA to pass object of main

Comment: The dependency injecting point should always be a constructor.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but i strongly think every coder should be free to follow their style, unless they are making code for public use

Comment: Of course you have a free choice to not use good practices. As of you can also decide to not use valid architecture or design. It is all up to you - until you're coding only for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@step

You can call private method from Main under the GroupA class, but this is a dirty hack and I don't recommend it; it is better to redesign the dataflow in the classes.
But here you go:

```
class GroupA
{
    private $requiredPrivateMethod;

    public function __construct(callable $requiredPrivateMethod)
    {
        $this->requiredPrivateMethod = $requiredPrivateMethod;
    }

    public function call(...$params) : void
    {
        \call_user_func($this->requiredPrivateMethod, ...$params);
    }
}

class Main
{
    private function methodC() : void
    {
        echo 'called private methodC';
    }

    public function groupA()
    {
        $that = $this;
        return new GroupA(function() use ($that) {
            $that->methodC();
        });
    }
}

$main = new Main();
// call private method Main::methodC from GroupA::call
$main->groupA()->call();
```

Comment: I dont want call function directly as groupA()->call(), but only inside functions of Group classes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little changes structure like this which works as excepted, but I want call() function as protected or private:

```
class Main
{
    public function call($params)
    {
        //some stuff
    }

    public function SubMain()
    {
        return new SubMain($this);
    }
}

class SubMain extends Base
{
    public function ClassA()
    {
        return new ClassA($this->parent);
    }
}

class Base
{
    protected $parent;

    public function __construct($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

}
class ClassA extends Base
{
    public function FunctionA($params)
    {
        return $this->parent->call($params);
    }

}
$iw = new Main();
$result = $iw->SubMain()->ClassA()->FunctionA($params);
```

What to do if I want call() function protected or private please?